# How to use SUMIF if criteria contains a ">" symbol?

Tags: excel

So I tried using the SUMIF formula as follows:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A10, ">30D", B1:B10)
```

Within my criteria range, there are instances of '>30D' occurring as a value. For instance, my data would look like this:

```
A        B
>30D     200
0-7D     100
8-14D    200
15D-29D  300
>30D     400
```

And I would like the formula to return 600. However, in the above formula, I'm getting the wrong values (double checked with a pivot table). I think this is because Excel is is interpreting ">30D" as an expression instead of a value. I've also tried referencing the cell itself with:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A10, $A$1, B1:B10)
```

This doesn't work either. Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `=` in front:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"=" & A1,B:B)
```

Or

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"=>30D",B:B)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(A1:A5,1)=">")*(B1:B5))
```

[image]

Comment: Just found an easier way around - if you try:
 `=SUMIF(A1:A10, "*>30D*", B1:B10)`

Then Excel will read it as text/string, and not as an expression :).